# Qubes-OS transfer files from and to HVM

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, qubes

I can't find in the documentation how to transfer data from and to the [HVM](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/hvm/) in [Qubes-OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/). When a normal AppVM is created, it has the Qubes Tools installed so easy copy and paste, and [transferring files](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/copying-files/) is possible. However, a HVM seems completely locked down.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can copy files between HVM⟺HVM & HVM⟺AppVM.
I didn't find any way in Qubes Documentation to do that.
I guess developers of Qubes didn't give this feature still.
But, I found way to do this.

First time what you have to do:

1. Create a virtual disk image.
2. Attach it to any VM(except dom0).
3. Identify the disk image using fdisk.
4. Create partition(s).
5. Create filesystem in that partition.
6. Detach from that VM

Every time what you have to do:

1. Attach it to target VM(HVM or AppVM).
2. Identify the disk image using fdisk.
3. Mount that volume.
4. Copy or Move whatever you want.
5. Unmount that volume.
6. Detach from that VM.
7. Do same to another VM(HVM or AppVM) for Paste.

Commands to do:

Creating virtual disk image (in dom0 Terminal):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/anaconda/storage.img bs=1M seek=20480 count=0
```

Replace 'anaconda' by your username; the number after seek is disk size in MB.

Attaching disk image to a VM (in dom0 Terminal):
 For Qubes-3.2

```
qvm-block -A VMname dom0:/home/anaconda/storage.img
```

For Qubes-4.0

```
sudo losetup -f --show /home/anaconda/storage.img


qvm-block attach VMname dom0:loop21
```

Identifying disk image (in VM Terminal):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Creating partition (in VM Terminal):

```
sudo fdisk /dev/xvdi
```

Creating filesystem in partition (in VM Terminal):

```
sudo mkfs.fat /dev/xvdi1
```

Mounting volume (in VM Terminal):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/removable

sudo mount /dev/xvdi1 /mnt/removable
```

Unmounting volume (in VM Terminal):

```
sudo umount /dev/xvdi1
```

Detaching disk image from VM (in dom0 Terminal):

```
qvm-block

qvm-block -d dom0:loop21
```

For Qubes-4.0 replace '-d' by 'detach'.

For video tutorial go to this link
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qE06DWWf97E

Comment: why do you use `seek=20480` in the `dd`? And why do it in dom0 when you can create the image in any AppVM?